# where to store current user data locally in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

sorry I am a newbie. as far as I know, There are two options to save/cache data locally, either using Shared Preference or using Hive.

say for example, I have User Model like this

```
class User {
  final String uid;
  final String fullname;
  final String email;
  final String domicile;
  final String profilePicturePath;
  final bool verified;
  final bool banned;
  List<String> attendedEventIDs;
  List<String> followingUserIDs;
  final int numberOfFollowers;
  final int numberOfApprovedEvents;
  final String description;
  final List<Event> upcomingEvents;
}
```

the current user who is using my app will get his data from server, and then I will use the current user instance in a lot of place in my app, so I think I should save it locally.

but if I save it to shared preference, it seems to me that that model above a little bit complicated to be saved in shared preference, even though I can serialize it first to string( I feel a little bit hacky to use this method). but if I use Hive/Sqlite, I feel a little bit overkill to just save one record to Hive

where to store current user data locally that commonly used in Flutter? or is there any other method available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing just this one thing on the device, I'd go with Shared Preferences. It's easy enough to have helper methods for your user class `fromMap`, `toMap`, `fromJson`, `toJson`. When you want to store in Shared Preferences, you call `toJson` to convert it to a string. When you want to convert it back to a user class, you just call `fromJson` and it'll take the string from Shared Preferences and return a `User` instance.

Of course, you could go with Hive and have this done for you but IMO it's a bit overkill for this.

User class:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class User {
  final String uid;
  final String fullname;
  final String email;
  final String domicile;
  final String profilePicturePath;
  final bool verified;
  final bool banned;
  List<String> attendedEventIDs;
  List<String> followingUserIDs;
  final int numberOfFollowers;
  final int numberOfApprovedEvents;
  final String description;
  final List<Event> upcomingEvents;

  User({
    this.uid,
    this.fullname,
    this.email,
    this.domicile,
    this.profilePicturePath,
    this.verified,
    this.banned,
    this.attendedEventIDs,
    this.followingUserIDs,
    this.numberOfFollowers,
    this.numberOfApprovedEvents,
    this.description,
    this.upcomingEvents,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'uid': uid,
      'fullname': fullname,
      'email': email,
      'domicile': domicile,
      'profilePicturePath': profilePicturePath,
      'verified': verified,
      'banned': banned,
      'attendedEventIDs': attendedEventIDs,
      'followingUserIDs': followingUserIDs,
      'numberOfFollowers': numberOfFollowers,
      'numberOfApprovedEvents': numberOfApprovedEvents,
      'description': description,
      'upcomingEvents': upcomingEvents?.map((x) => x.toMap())?.toList(),
    };
  }

  factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return User(
      uid: map['uid'],
      fullname: map['fullname'],
      email: map['email'],
      domicile: map['domicile'],
      profilePicturePath: map['profilePicturePath'],
      verified: map['verified'],
      banned: map['banned'],
      attendedEventIDs: List<String>.from(map['attendedEventIDs']),
      followingUserIDs: List<String>.from(map['followingUserIDs']),
      numberOfFollowers: map['numberOfFollowers'],
      numberOfApprovedEvents: map['numberOfApprovedEvents'],
      description: map['description'],
      upcomingEvents: List<Event>.from(map['upcomingEvents']?.map((x) => Event.fromMap(x))),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory User.fromJson(String source) => User.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```